# Wordpress not caching properly

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, caching

I'm trying to get my wordpress site to cache, and no matter what I do, it wont cache properly.

When running google page insights I keep getting this result

[image]

I have tried installing wordpress plugins and modifying my htaccess as so

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/svg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<filesmatch "\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|swf|svg)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, public"
</filesmatch>
<filesmatch "\.(html|htm)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, private, must-revalidate"
</filesmatch>
<filesmatch "\.(pdf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
</filesmatch>
<filesmatch "\.(js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, private"
</filesmatch>
```

Whenever I load the website and check google chrome developer network tools, it shows

```
 no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
```

What am I missing? I need to improve the page's speed on page insights, and this is the biggest thing slowing it down.

*Note - I mainly develop hard coded sites, I'm new to building sites via wordpress, if theres some sort of setting im missing to turn it on or something, I wouldn't know!*

Answer (score 0):

Are you on shared hosting?

Do you have mod_expires enabled?

Those are 2 important factors, if you're on shared hosting try asking your provider if they have mod_expires enabled/installed.

Are you on Nginx or Apache2?

Comment: Its hosted on a server that contains about 200 other websites, all which caching works fine with no issues

Comment: Have you checked another domain's .htaccess and compared it?

Comment: Yes, there are no major differences.

Comment: Weird, do you have a plugin activated?